# Function, sorting/search with a onclick to show content - cant make it work wit multi (maybe be a JS im missing)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Making a function where I have some boxes where I have made a search funktion for multi boxes. for that part works, but when I click on the found one, a content should sh

```js
function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  
}
/* opsalgs værktøj */
var divs = ["Div5-show", "Div1-show", "Div2-show", "Div3-show", "Div4-show"];
      var visibleId = null;
      function showhide(id) {
        if(visibleId !== id) {
          visibleId = id;
        } 
        hide();
      }
      function hide() {
        var div, i, id;
        for(i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
          id = divs[i];
          div = document.getElementById(id);
          if(visibleId === id) {
            div.style.display = "block";
          } else {
            div.style.display = "none";
          }
        }
      }
```

```css
.grid-container-support {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr) ;
  
  column-gap: 1rem;
  row-gap: 1em;
}
.grid-item-support {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px; 
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px;  
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
} 
#myinput {
    text-align: center;

    }
```

```html
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Søg producenten.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()" onclick="myFunction()">
        <p>
        <div class="grid-container-support">
                <a class="grid-item-support" href="#" onclick="showhide('Div1-show');"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/?random=1"><br>Purple</a>
                <a class="grid-item-support" href="#" onclick="showhide('Div2-show');"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/?random=2"><br>Red</a>
                <a class="grid-item-support" href="#" onclick="showhide('Div3-show');"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/?random=3"><br>Yellow</a>
                <a class="grid-item-support" href="#" onclick="showhide('Div4-show');"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/?random=4"><br>Green</a>
                <a class="grid-item-support" href="#" onclick="showhide('Div5-show');"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/?random=5"><br>Blue</a>
        </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
    <div class="show-content">
        <div id="Div5-show" style="display: none;">
                        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
        <div id="Hp-show" style="display: none;">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
        <div id="Huwaei-show" style="display: none;">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
        <div id="Hpe-show" style="display: none;">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
        <div id="Asus-show" style="display: none;">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
    </div>
```

ow below, it work on "blue" but cant make it work on the others. It might be that I need some correction for my JS for it to work, but cant find out what it is, maybe one can help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9A6az.png)

Comment: The snippet does not work ... you are missing the myFunction that you call on click event...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

You set `divs = ["Div5-show", "Div1-show", "Div2-show", "Div3-show", "Div4-show"];`.

But there are not divs with id "Div1-show", "Div2-show", "Div3-show", "Div4-show". In HTML you have only "Div5-show" that's why it shows an error. Because it can't find divs with those ids.

**Solution:**

Rename "Hp-show", "Huwaei-show"... to "Div1-show", "Div2-show"...

Comment: Im new to this site, so I didnt edit the code correct, I can see that it works now, so many thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

The ids of the following divs need update...

```
        <div id="Hp-show" style="display: none;">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
        <div id="Huwaei-show" style="display: none;">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
        <div id="Hpe-show" style="display: none;">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
        <div id="Asus-show" style="display: none;">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
```

to

```
 <div id="Div1-show" style="display: none;">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
        <div id="Div2-show" style="display: none;">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
        <div id="Div3-show" style="display: none;">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
        <div id="Div4-show" style="display: none;">
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </div>
```